# usage of missover statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I have below dataset

```
data ab;
infile cards missover;
input m p c;
cards;
1,2,3
4,5,
6,7,
run;
```

The output of this query is

```
m p c
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

Why did i get the below output instead of error? 
I havent specified any delimiter also.
Please explain.

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Answer (score 0):

You do get INVALID DATA messages.  SAS is defaulting to space delimited fields, you need to specify the DSD INFILE statement option and or DLM=','.  You don't actually need MISSOVER as you have the proper number of delimiters for three comma delimited fields, but I would probably go ahead and keep it.

```
24         data ab;
25         infile cards missover;
26         input m p c;
27         cards;

NOTE: Invalid data for m in line 28 1-5.
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                     
28         1,2,3
m=. p=. c=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
NOTE: Invalid data for m in line 29 1-4.
29         4,5,
m=. p=. c=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
NOTE: Invalid data for m in line 30 1-4.
30         6,7,
m=. p=. c=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=3
NOTE: The data set WORK.AB has 3 observations and 3 variables.




24         data ab;
25         infile cards dsd missover;
26         input m p c;
27         cards;

NOTE: The data set WORK.AB has 3 observations and 3 variables.
```

Answer (score 0):

The MISSOVER is what makes you have three observations instead just one.  Without the MISSOVER then SAS will try to read each line as one value and you will end up with one observation of all missing values.  It is easier to see if you change your variables to character instead of numeric since you can see where the values end up.

```
data ab;
infile cards missover;
input m $ p $ c $;
put (m p c) (=);
cards;
1,2,3
4,5,
6,7,
;

m=1,2,3 p=  c=
m=4,5, p=  c=
m=6,7, p=  c=

data ab;
infile cards /*missover */;
input m $ p $ c $;
put (m p c) (=);
cards;
1,2,3
4,5,
6,7,
;

m=1,2,3 p=4,5, c=6,7,
NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
```